# something is causing a horizontal overflow on the body, but I can't tell what it is?

Tags: css

In the page below, something is causing some padding on the body or html on the right and that  overflow is causing a scroll on the x axis.

How can I remove that overflow?

I've already applied

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Here is the page: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/new.html

Does anyone know what is causing this overflow / space to the right, but inside the document and how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repaire the 5% margin overflow, I suggest changing the CSS for `#searchInput` to add `display:block;` and change margins to `margin:0px auto;`.

```
#searchInput {
  ...
  display: block;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your `#searchInput` - it has 90% width, 2x5% margin and border .. so the border causes it to go beyond 100%.

Comment: ah, bloody math! Thank you for reminding me about addition of the borders.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kaloyan Ivanov says, it comes from your `input` element. You just need to adjust borders and margins so that they together aren't more than 100% or you could also change the CSS box-model for this single input with:

```
input#searchInput {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```